# How to properly distribute js code for php foreach?

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

Have php foreach in file

```
<?php
  foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item):
    $sqlcartprod = mysqli_query(db(),"SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='".$item['product']."' ");
    $rowcartprod = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlcartprod);
?>
   <tr>
     <td class="shoping__cart__item">
        <img src="<?=$rowcartprod['ikonka']?>" width="101" alt="">
        <h5><?=$rowcartprod['name_'.$lang]?></h5>
     </td>
     <td class="shoping__cart__price" >
        <span id="priceprod"><?=$rowcartprod['price']?></span> azn
     </td>
     <td class="shoping__cart__quantity">
        <div class="quantity">
           <div class="pro-qty">
              <input type="text" style="cursor: default" readonly value="<?=$item['qty']?>">
           </div>
        </div>
     </td>
     <td class="shoping__cart__total" id="totalprice">
         <?=$item['price']*$item['qty']?> azn
     </td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

for this piece of code:

```
<div class="quantity">
  <div class="pro-qty">
    <input type="text" style="cursor: default" readonly value="<?=$item['qty']?>">
  </div>
</div>
```

have JS code:

```
var proQty = $('.pro-qty');
proQty.prepend('<span class="dec qtybtn">-</span>');
proQty.append('<span class="inc qtybtn">+</span>');
proQty.on('click', '.qtybtn', function () {

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find('input').val();


    if ($button.hasClass('inc')) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue > 0) {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
            newVal = 0;
        }
    }
    $button.parent().find('input').val(newVal);

        var Price = document.getElementById('priceprod').innerText;
        var Tprice = document.getElementById('totalprice');
        
        if (Price[i] > 0) {
            Tprice.textContent = (Price[i] * newVal) + ' azn';
        }
});
```

The issue is that when I click on qtybtn + or qtybtn -, the js code works only for the first product in the shopping list, even if there are 2,3 or more products in the list. I tried to separate inside the js code with loops, but then the js code somehow stops working at all. How to distribute correctly so that the js code works for each product separately?

Comment: You're generating invalid markup. You have multiple elements with the same id, because you create `<span id="priceprod">` in a loop. So `getElementById` grabs the first one.

Comment: I added in foreach loop `$a++` for `<span id="priceprod">`, but how to show `$a++` in js code?

Comment: No need for that, actually. You could use a class instead. Think of it this way - when the quantity buttons are clicked, you need to find the span that is their closest. Determine the element that is the common parent of both the buttons and the span. You select the parent of the clicked button and then find the span of your chosen class inside that parent.

Comment: In theory, I understand what you want to say, but I honestly don't know how to do it in practice.

Comment: @El_Vanja, I find jquery methods closest, find and parent. But how to arrange it correctly?

Comment: Just follow through the structure. In JS event handlers, you can access the element that was clicked through `event.target`. Then you need to move up to reach the necessary parent. As far as I can see, calling parent twice on the event target should get you your `tr`. Then you can use `find` on it to reach the span.

Comment: @El_Vanja, For Price I write `var Price = $('.shoping__cart__price').parent().find('span').text();`, but this show me all products in list prices

Comment: That's because you used a class selector, `$('.shoping__cart__price')`. You need to use `event.target`. Add the event as a parameter in your handler (`function (event) {`) and then you can use the event target, which will be the specific button that was clicked.

Comment: @El_Vanja, at morning im back for my issue, now its late time for me. Thank you very much for helping to me in my question

Comment: @El_Vanja, Hi. For `Price` I write `var Price = $(event.target).parent('tr').find('span#priceprod').text();`, but this `console.log(Price)` show me empty string in console and `console.log(event.target)` show me `<span class="inc qtybtn">+</span>`. Whats I do wrong?

Comment: If you check the manual, [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) goes up only one level, and the immediate parent is `td`, not `tr`. You could try simply calling parent twice successively `$(event.target).parent().parent()`.

Comment: @El_Vanja, show again empty `var Price = $(event.target).parent().parent().find('span#priceprod').text();
            console.log(Price)`

Comment: @El_Vanja, this is help and show me `span` value right `var Price = $(event.target).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('span#priceprod').text();` :)

Comment: @El_Vanja, now I trying change text for `Totalprice`. This way I find my total price `var Tprice = $(event.target).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('span#totalprice').text();`. In console show right. `var NewPrice = (Price * newVal) + ' azn';
            Tprice.textContent(NewPrice);` Give me error `Tprice.textContent is not a function` and this too error `var NewPrice = (Price * newVal) + ' azn';
            Tprice.textContent(NewPrice);` (((

Comment: @El_Vanja, I founded. Problem was this `find('span#totalprice')`. TotalPrice not have `span`, only `td`.

Comment: @El_Vanja, Thank you very much for your help, you just have no idea how grateful I am to you. Now minus one smut pain. Thank you, good luck to you.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help and to see you ultimately found your own way through it.